# Are IIS logs affected by Daylight savings time?

Tags: iis, daylight-saving

It seems as if IIS logs are timestamped with the current UTC time.  Will the timestamps in IIS logs be offset an hour during daylight savings time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UTC time does not observe day light saving time.  So no it will not have any of those issues. So for example EST is UTC-5 and EDT is UTC-4 (Eastern Standard Time and Eastern Daylight Time).